# how to prevent ruby from defining variables

Tags: ruby

I'd like a user to input a conditional expression interactively, something like `f1 == 'b' || f2 == 'd'` where *f1* and *f2* are ruby functions. `eval condition` works ok. However, I'd like to prevent errors like `f3 = 'c'` where *f3* is not defined in ruby. Ruby silently defines a local variable. I'd like to capture an error instead.

So, is there a way to prevent ruby from creating local variables or a way to capture a creation event?

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

class Conditions
    def f1
        "a"
    end

    def f2
        "b"
    end

    def evalCondition(cond)
        begin
            eval cond
        rescue => ex
            puts ex
        end
    end
end


def evalCondition(cond)
    conds = Conditions.new
    conds.evalCondition(cond)
end


puts evalCondition("f1 == 'x'")
puts evalCondition("f1 == 'a' || f2 == 'b'")
puts evalCondition("f3 = 'y'")
```

I'd like to catch the last one as an error.

Comment: As a workaround, you can do `"c" == f3`

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] of the "user input", and explain why you want to prevent creating a local variables? (That's an odd thing to restrict in isolation; are you happy for them to enter `'rm -rf / --no-reserve-root' `, but `hello = "world"` is not allowed?!)

Comment: @TomLord: it's `--no-preserve-root` actually :)

Comment: It's also only dangerous if the user entered back-ticks, not apostrophes, but I couldn't figure out how to format back-ticks-within-back-ticks in a StackOverflow comment ... Edit: OK, it's `\`rm -rf / --no-preserve-root\``

Comment: In summary: If you're calling `eval` on arbitrary user input, then "defining a local variable" should be the **least** of your concerns!! But without knowing any context of how this program works, or what you're trying to achieve, it's difficult to offer a suggestion.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: could you `gsub` every function with `send(:someFunction)`?

Comment: @TomLord yeah, i have not thought about backticks. Thanks for the idea. At least I could capture it :-). But there are other ways as well.

Comment: @CassianoFranco I am looking for an easy way :-).  I'd like to avoid parsing the expression string on my own.

Comment: Can I assume the expression splitted by spaces will always have odd length and bigger then 2?

Comment: @CassianoFranco unfortunately no.

Comment: You said "I'd like a user to input a conditional expression interactively", and yet your code same does not involve capturing user input. I presume there's actually a `gets`  at the bottom?

Comment: I still don't really understand the scope of the problem, though -- Why are you running a program in this way? Why are you only concerned about this one specific harmless way that the user can enter "bad" input, and not the infinite other ways that a user could enter malicious input?

Comment: The user could also enter `system('rm -rf / --no-preserve-root')` to bypass your security check and delete every file on the machine. That's a little bit more concerning than defining a local variable.

Comment: @TomLord based on the discussion, I had to rethink the issue. Now I'd like to avoid any side effects which could be caused by the user input in ruby environment while calculating the conditional expression. So, I ended up analyzing every element in the string for availability of the function and/or allowed set of logical operators.  The input source itself does not matter, it ends up as a  string in the code. I did not include it in the example.

Comment: @Serge *"The input source itself does not matter, it ends up as a string in the code"* -- What matters is whether you can **trust** the input source. Is it defined in the code, or sent by a user? Do you trust the user not to be malicious (e.g. is it an internal tool, or available to the public)?

Comment: So... Perhaps using `eval` is actually OK, and you shouldn't really worry about handling this edge case? Or perhaps you could define the user input to work differently, and follow a well-defined format, instead of an arbitrary string? Or perhaps you could instead implement a "safe evaluation" via a library like https://github.com/project-eutopia/keisan instead of a scary `eval`!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to check if some local variables is created, but you need bind a context in the eval

```rb
class Context
  def f1
    return 'a'
  end

  def f2
    return 'b'
  end

  def get_binding
    binding
  end
end

context = Context.new
bind = context.get_binding

eval("a = f1 == 'b' || f2 == 'b'", bind)
variables = eval('self.local_variables', bind)

throw "undefined variables: " + variables.join(' ') if (variables.size)
```